# Coalesce null across multiple rows

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table in this form

```
 id_customer__ |        status         |     time_stmpd_at     | idx
---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----
        112220 | enabled____________at | 2017-12-13 16:12:42.0 |   1
        112220 | sale_locked_at__      | 2017-12-13 14:52:43.0 |   2
        112220 | qual_sale_at          | 2017-12-06 12:22:50.0 |   3
        112220 | quality_control___at  | 2017-11-28 18:22:02.0 |   4
        112220 | returned__at          | 2017-10-12 23:02:41.0 |   5
```

I would like the `status` where `idx` = 2 and the `time_stmpd_at` where the idx = 1. And be able to do this for all customer ids.

I have tried to put the conditions into the select statement like so:

```
select
  id_customer__,
  if(idx=2, status, NULL) as previous_status,
  if(idx=1, time_stmpd_at, NULL) as time_stmpd_at
from htable
```

But this leaves me with

```
 id_customer__ | previous_status  |      time_stmpd_at
---------------+------------------+-----------------------
        119650 | NULL             | 2017-12-13 16:12:42.0
        119650 | sale_locked_at__ | NULL
        119650 | NULL             | NULL
        119650 | NULL             | NULL
        119650 | NULL             | NULL
```

Next I would have to coalesce the field down to a single row. But I feel that there must be a better way. Any advice on the overall approach?

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: Presto, may need Hive version, but from the answers it looks transferrable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.

```
select
  id_customer__,
  max(case when idx=2 then status end) as previous_status,
  max(case when idx=1 then time_stmpd_at end) as time_stmpd_at
from htable
group by id_customer__
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use MAX and limit the table to only indexes you want (you don't have to do that but why bother calculating on rows that are irrelevant):

```
SELECT id_customer__, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN idx=1 THEN time_stmpd_at ELSE NULL END) time_stmpd_at,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idx=2 THEN status ELSE NULL END) status
FROM htable 
WHERE idx IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id_customer__
```

Or you could pull those indexes separetely and join them on `id_customer__`

```
SELECT h1.id_customer__, h1.time_stmpd_at , h2.status 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM htable WHERE idx=1) h1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM htable WHERE idx=2) h2 ON h1.id_customer__ = h2.id_customer__
```

Answer (score 0):

(Based on @VamsiPrabhala answer but changed to use `arbitrary` aggregation)

I would recommend using `arbitrary` aggregation (instead of `max`), as it conveys the meaning better:

```
select id_customer,
  arbitrary(status) filter(where idx=2) as previous_status,
  arbitrary(time_stmpd_at) filter(where idx=1) as time_stmpd_at
from htable
group by id_customer
```

There are 2 reasons to use `arbitrary`:

1. `arbitrary` signals you're not doing any `max` aggregation (this is good in case someone reads this query in the future)
2. there isn't any aggregation that would reject multiple values. If there were, I would recommend using that over `arbitrary`